# Create row of view object if not existing

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I have a page with a view object that returns a single row. My intention is to create a row if it's not existing. When entering the page if a row with the certain key exists, the page loads and can also be updated well.
When the row with the certain key doesn't exist, the page is not loading correct. The createrow method from the view object is not called.
I think I am missing something in my pageDef.

I have tried with invokeAction

```
<invokeAction id="initEmptyRowSet" Binds="Rollback" Refresh="always"
                  RefreshCondition="#{bindings.MyVO1Iterator.queryModel == null}"/>
```

or

```
<invokeAction Binds="EventTypesExecuteWithParams" id="invokeEventTypes“ Refresh="ifNeeded"/>

<action IterBinding="MyVO1Iterator“ id="EventTypesExecuteWithParams"
    InstanceName="MyAppModuleDataControl.AccidentIVVVO"
    DataControl="MyAppModuleDataControl" RequiresUpdateModel="true"
    Action="executeWithParams">
</action>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the CreateInsert operation on the VOIterator conditionally.
Here your condition is if VOIterator row count is > 0, then don't insert new row else execute the iterator to query the VO.

Here is the sample code.

```
<iterator Binds="AccidentIVVVO" RangeSize="25"
     DataControl="MyAppModuleDataControl" id="MyVO1Iterator"/>

<invokeAction id="createInsert" Binds="CreateInsert"
     RefreshCondition="#{bindings.MyVO1Iterator.estimatedRowCount == 0}"
     Refresh="ifNeeded"/>

<action IterBinding="MyVO1Iterator" id="CreateInsert" 
    InstanceName="MyAppModuleDataControl.MyVO1"
    DataControl="MyAppModuleDataControl"
    RequiresUpdateModel="true" Action="createInsertRow"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the respones!! Now I have two invokeActions one with Binds="CreateInsert" and one with Binds="ExecuteWithParams", depending on the estimatedRowCount. Now the createInsert triggers even when the row exists. Maybe I am missing now on the Refresh attribute?

Comment: Correct..!! and conditionally call the invikeActions depending upon your requirement.

Comment: Nope, it won't trigger as you have restricted the refresh condition by estimatedRowCount == 0

Comment: Thanks Ashok, I accepted your response as answer. Thanks for everything

Comment: Sorry for bringing it up but just to clear things. Does the refresh attribute play any role as to which one will execute first? Should one of them be different?
I get weird results with this. estimatedRowCount is 1 even when it was supposed to be empty. Does the following seem ok ?
<invokeAction id="createInsert" Binds="CreateInsert"
     RefreshCondition="#{bindings.MyVO1Iterator.estimatedRowCount == 0}"
     Refresh="ifNeeded"/>
<invokeAction id="createInsert" Binds="ExecuteWithParams"
     RefreshCondition="#{bindings.MyVO1Iterator.estimatedRowCount != 0}"
     Refresh="default"/>

Comment: No, the refresh attribute doesn't help in anyway for execution order. It only defines at what time it will be refreshed. The execution order purely depends on the sequence of invoke action. The weird issue you are talking about may be happening if you are reopening that page. Because, the first time you open the page, it will insert a blank  row in the VO and it will remain in the session. The next time, the row count will be 1 as already you have a row in VO. So, you have to remove the empty row before coming out of the page. Let me know if you need more clarification. Happy Coding.. :)